# How to write the result of a running program in a logfile that would change name everyday (date in the filename)?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to know if it's possible using the linux command line to achieve logging in a file using the current time.

Let's say I run: 
`node somescript.js > /tmp/logfile-DATE.log 2>&1 &`

And every day the logfile will change name for the new date.

I'd really prefer not to code the file logging logic in the program.

Btw I'm on Ubuntu 18.

Thanks.

Comment: It's possible. But it's better use system logging utitlities like `journalctl` or `logger` or `syslog` and do logrotating with `logrotate`.

Comment: Do you re-run `node somescript.js` every day as well?

Comment: No it should never have to stop.

Comment: KamilCuk, I'd use logrotate but it would probably kill the pipe between the logfile and the program. Do you have any easy example of journaling the logs the way I intend to ? Thx

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/291368/log-rotation-of-stdout

Comment: Thx Ente, I'll into these programs. Bests.

Comment: These programs are really old an unsupported anymore. Not reliable enough. But thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If none of the log-rotation programs suggested by by @ente` are available/works, consider rolling your own.

If the volume of messages from the node server i low (few messages per minute), a `bash` script (sample below) will do. If the volume is large, consider using a stronger engine (Perl, python) or a c/c++ program for high-volume.

Using `bash` for low-volume, checking for date change every 60 second to avoid expensive calls to date. Format of log file can be adjusted by changing the date command.

```
#! /bin/bash -ue
function dynamic_logger {
    local date_fmt='/tmp/logfile-%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'
    local curr_log=$(date +"$date_fmt")
    echo "Start LOG $curr_log" >&2
    exec 1>>$curr_log
    local last_ts=$SECONDS
    while read l ; do
        now=$SECONDS
        if ((now-last_ts>60)) ; then
            last_ts=$now
            next_log=$(date +"$date_fmt")
            if [[ "$next_log" != "$curr_log" ]] ; then
                curr_log=$next_log
                echo "Change LOG $curr_log" >&2
                exec 1>>$curr_log
            fi
        fi
        printf '%s\n' "$l"
    done
}

node something.js 2>&1 | dynamic_logger
```

For faster performance, consider the equivalent `perl` script. It takes the `strftime` format as input. Store as "my-log", and execute with

```
node javascript.js 2>&1 | my-log
```

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict ;
use POSIX qw(strftime) ;

my $log_fmt = shift @ARGV ;

my $last_ts = time ;
my $curr_log = strftime($log_fmt, localtime) ;
open STDOUT, '>>', $curr_log or die ;
print STDERR "Start Log: $curr_log\n" ;
while ( <> ) {
    my $now = time ;
    if ( $now-$last_ts > 10 ) {
        $last_ts = $now ;
        my $next_log = strftime($log_fmt, localtime) ;
        if ( $next_log ne $curr_log ) {
            $curr_log = $next_log ;
            open STDOUT, '>>', $curr_log or die ;
            print STDERR "Change Log: $curr_log\n" ;
        } ;
        print $_;

    } ;
} ;
```

Comment: Ended up coding it inside, it gets over 1000+ log entries per minutes. Thanks for your example!

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
node somescript.js > /tmp/logfile-`date "+\%a.log"` 2>&1 &
```

You can replace the %a with whatever you want from the date command. The \ in front of the % is there in case you want to have it work with cron. It is not needed if you are doing it from the command line.

Comment: No it would only 'dynamically' create the logfile with today's date. But tomorrow it would still be writing in that logfile and not one with tomorrow's date in the name.

Comment: To do that you will need to do the logging inside the script. Supplying the filename on the command line will not give you the ability to switch to a new log each day without restarting the program.